# Merge a daily data.frame with an annual data.frame

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I want to merge two data frames. One contains daily data and the other one annual data.
How can I do that?

```
date <- c("05.06.2001","02.10.2003","06.12.2004","01.01.2001","01.04.2003")
company <- c(1,1,1,2,2)

mydf <- data.frame(date, company)
mydf

#         date company
# 1 05.06.2001       1
# 2 02.10.2003       1
# 3 06.12.2004       1
# 4 01.01.2001       2
# 5 01.04.2003       2

# annual data

YEAR <- c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005)
COMPANY <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
VARIABLE <- c(120, 230, 99, 38, 21, 20, 24, 420, 203, 180)

annual <- data.frame(YEAR, COMPANY, VARIABLE)
annual

#    YEAR COMPANY VARIABLE
# 1  2001       1      120
# 2  2002       1      230
# 3  2003       1       99
# 4  2004       1       38
# 5  2005       1       21
# 6  2001       2       20
# 7  2002       2       24
# 8  2003       2      420
# 9  2004       2      203
# 10 2005       2      180

# the output should be:

#         date company VARIABLE
# 1 05.06.2001       1      120
# 2 02.10.2003       1       99
# 3 06.12.2004       1       38
# 4 01.01.2001       2       20
# 5 01.04.2003       2      420
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

#### Option 1: Use package `lubridate`

```
require(luubridate)   ## install it first if you don't have it
mydf$year <- year(mydf$date)
merged.df <- merge(mydf, annual, by.x=c('company', 'year'), by.y=c('COMPANY', 'YEAR'))
```

#### Option 2: Use `data.table`

The package `data.table` is a bit more of an investment (highly recommended), and it has built-in functions to handle dates. It has a lot of other fantastic features too (fast merging, and grouping, lower memory use) and would make the merging process much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions. In these (except the sqldf solution) we will use the following functions:

```
d2y <- function(date) as.numeric(substring(date, 7))
lower.names <- function(DF) setNames(DF, tolower(names(DF)))
```

**Base R** Here is a base solution.  Although its not the situation in the example, to be safe we perform a *left* join in case there are any dates in `mydf` that do not have corresponding years in `annual`.  The left join will ensure that such dates are not dropped:

```
mydf2 <- transform(mydf, year = d2y(date))
merge(mydf2, lower.names(annual), all.x = TRUE)
```

**sqldf** Here is an sqldf solution.  This is a bit neater since we do not have to materialize `mydf2` but instead we can directly join on a complex logical expression.  Note that this solution does not use `d2y` or `lower.names`:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select mydf.company, year, date, VARIABLE as variable
       from mydf left join annual 
       on mydf.company = annual.company and year = substr(date, 7)")
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %.% 
  mutate(year = d2y(date)) %.%
  left_join(lower.names(annual))
```

**data.table**  Below we could have used data.table's `setnames` had we been willing to modify `annual` in place but here opted for the non-destructive `setNames` instead:

```
library(data.table)

key <- c("company", "year")
mydt <- setkeyv(data.table(mydf)[, year := d2y(date)], key)
data.table(lower.names(annual), key = key)[mydt]
```